# Why is my function to change the innerText of a targeted button changing the innerText of all the buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach, addeventlistener

This is my first JS project.
I am creating a study scheduler where the user inputs a to-do item and assigns it to a day.
JS creates the necessary elements (input field, trash button, completed button, start time button and end time button).  I'm having a problem with the time picker.
I wrote a function that unhides a clock (that I wrote in html) when the user clicks on a startButton (that is created in JS). There can be unlimited startButtons so I wrote an eventListener for the array of these buttons.
The user picks the hour, minutes, and am/pm, which all get stored in variables, and then when they click the setTimeButton, the targeted startButton.innerText should update to show this time.  The first time I run the function it works. After that, it is changing the targeted startButton plus every previous startTime button that I have clicked.
Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => 
  Array.from(startButton).forEach(element => 
    element.addEventListener('click', showTimePicker)
) );

function showTimePicker(e) { 

  let startOrEndTimeButton = e.target           
  // show clock
  Array.from(time).forEach(element => element.classList.toggle('hide')) 

  // click setTimeButton to insert time into targeted start time or end time button
  setTimeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    startOrEndTimeButton.innerText = chosenHour.innerText 
                                  + ':' + chosenMinutes.innerText 
                                  + " " + chosenAmPm.innerText;
    startOrEndTimeButton.style.backgroundColor = '#39ff14';
    startOrEndTimeButton.style.color = 'white';   
    Array.from(time).forEach(element => element.classList.toggle('hide')); 
  })
}
```

Comment: each time a `startButton` you create a new `setTimeButton` EventListener. 1000 clicks on any `startButton`  will create 1000 new EventListener on  `setTimeButton`... and any click on ` setTimeButton` will call 1000 time his inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your app's logic and the problematic behaviour that you describe:

- Clicking on one of the buttons and then clicking the `Set` button, will change the value of that particular button
- Clicking on another button and then clicking on the `Set` button will change the value of the selected button **and also the value of the previously selected button**.

```js
const setTimeButton = document.getElementById("set");
const startButton = document.querySelectorAll("button.st");
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => 
    Array.from( startButton )
    .forEach( element => element.addEventListener( 'click', showTimePicker ) ) );

function showTimePicker( e ) {

    let startOrEndTimeButton = e.target
    setTimeButton.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
      console.log("event handler changing:", startOrEndTimeButton);

      startOrEndTimeButton.innerText = (Math.random() * 1000).toFixed();

    })

}
```

```html
<button class="st one">Start 1</button>
<button class="st two">Start 2</button>
<button class="st three">Start 3</button>
<button id="set">Set</button>
```

Here are the changes you should make, in order for the app to work as expected:

1. Define the `startOrEndTimeButton` variable outside the `showTimePicker`.
2. Move the `setTimeoutButton` outside the `showTimePicker`.

As **Mister Jojo** correctly pointed out, you do not want to set an `Event Listener` on the `setTimeoutButton` every time you click on a `startButton`.

You can **Run the code snippets** in these two examples and check the resulting behavior yourself. Study the code carefully in order to understand why the suggested changes affect the behavior of the program and leave a comment in case you have any question about the suggested changes.

```js
const setTimeButton = document.getElementById("set");
const startButton = document.querySelectorAll("button.st");
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => 
    Array.from( startButton )
    .forEach( element => element.addEventListener( 'click', showTimePicker ) ) );

let startOrEndTimeButton;

function showTimePicker( e ) {
    startOrEndTimeButton = e.target
}

setTimeButton.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
  startOrEndTimeButton.innerText = (Math.random() * 1000).toFixed();
})
```

```html
<button class="st">Start 1</button>
<button class="st">Start 2</button>
<button class="st">Start 3</button>
<button id="set">Set</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution.  I understand why the changes you made work and I understand that I was creating a new event listener with every startButton click.  What I don't understand is, since I made startOrEndTimeButton = e.target, how is the code changing elements that are not e.target?

Comment: Great question. It's actually the previous addEventListener callback that is changing the previous element that was set via startOrEndTimeButton = e.target. I've updated  the first snippet so you can see the value of startOrEndTimeButton at each handler call.

Comment: The event handler callback 'remembers' the initial e.target value that was set when showTimePicker was called.

Comment: So the event handler is creating an array of e.targets and then looping through the array every time I click on it?  I think there is a gap in my knowledge that is preventing me from understanding why it would do this.  What JS subject should I study to learn more about this?  Callbacks?

Comment: I think the most important concept here is 'Closures'.